# Slider update values in datatable R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to filter the data in a datatable based from the inputs from the slider range. When this is done I get an error `subscript out of bounds`. I see the slider range to be working fine. But the range doesnt  seems to filter the data table.

Below is the code which I have used :

```
    response_codes <- function(status_code){

  status_df <- tibble::tribble(
    ~status_code, ~message,
    200,    "Success",
    201,    "Successfully created item",
    204,    "Item deleted successfully",
    400,    "Something was wrong with the format of your request",
    401,    "Unauthorized - your API key is invalid",
    403,    "Forbidden - you do not have access to operate on the requested item(s)",
    404,    "Item not found",
    429,    "Request was throttled - you are sending too many requests too fast."
  )

  out <- status_df[status_df$status_code == status_code, "message"]

  out <- unlist(out, use.names = FALSE)

  out
}
install.packages("devtools")
library(tidyr)
lego_get <- function(url, ..., api_key){

  auth <- paste("key", api_key)

  query = list(...)

  # Call the apiå
  api_call <- httr::GET(url, query = query,
                        httr::add_headers(Authorization = auth))

  if(httr::status_code(api_call) > 204){
    stop(response_codes(httr::status_code(api_call)))
  } else {
    message(response_codes(httr::status_code(api_call)))
  }

  # Collect data
  out <- list()

  api_data <- httr::content(api_call)

  if(is.null(api_data$results)){
    api_data <- null_to_na(api_data)
    return(api_data)
  }

  if(length(api_data$results) == 0){
    api_data$results <- NA
    api_data <- null_to_na(api_data)
    return(api_data)
  }

  out <- c(out, list(api_data$results))

  # While loop to deal with pagination
  while(!is.null(api_data$`next`)){
    message(paste("Pagenating to:", api_data$`next`))
    api_call <- httr::GET(api_data$`next`, httr::add_headers(Authorization = auth))
    api_data <- httr::content(api_call)
    out <- c(out, list(api_data$results))
  }

  # Flatten the list
  out <- purrr::flatten(out)

  # Set nulls to NA
  out <- null_to_na(out)

  # Return data
  out

}

null_to_na <- function(mylist){
  purrr::map(mylist, function(x){
    if(is.list(x)){
      null_to_na(x)
    } else {
      if(is.null(x)) NA else x
    }
  })
}

color_list_to_df <- function(lego_data){
  out <- purrr::map_df(lego_data, function(color){

    external_ids <- names(color$external_ids)

    col_df <- purrr::map_df(external_ids, function(external_id){
      ext_ids <- unlist(color$external_ids[[external_id]]$ext_ids)

      df <- tibble::tibble(
        external_id = external_id,
        ext_ids = ext_ids
      )

      ext_descrs <- color$external_ids[[external_id]]$ext_descrs
      ext_descrs <- purrr::map(ext_descrs, unlist)

      df$ext_descrs <- ext_descrs

      df <- tidyr::unnest(df, ext_descrs)

      df
    })

    external <- tidyr::nest(col_df, .key = external_ids)

    tibble::tibble(
      id = color$id,
      name = color$name,
      rgb = color$rgb,
      is_trans = color$is_trans,
      external_ids = external$external_ids
    )
  })

  out
}

parts_list_to_df <- function(lego_data){
  out <- purrr::map_df(lego_data, function(parts_data){

    if(length(parts_data$external_ids) != 0){
      part_df <- tibble::tibble(
        external_ids = names(parts_data$external_ids)
      )

      part_df$ids <- purrr::map(part_df$external_ids, function(ext_name){
        unlist(parts_data$external_ids[[ext_name]])
      })

      part_df <- tidyr::unnest(part_df, ids)

      external <- tidyr::nest(part_df, .key = external_ids)
    } else {
      external <- list()
      external$external_ids <- NA
    }

    tibble::tibble(
      part_num = parts_data$part_num,
      name = parts_data$name,
      part_cat_id = parts_data$part_cat_id,
      part_url = parts_data$part_url,
      part_img_url = parts_data$part_img_url,
      external_ids = external$external_ids
    )
  })

  out
}




###############################################################
url <- "https://rebrickable.com/api/v3/lego/sets/"
api_key <- "5baf593383d5f6a7fadd264480287ac9"

lego_data <- lego_get(url = url, api_key = api_key)

message("Converting to tibble")
out <- purrr::map_df(lego_data, tibble::as_tibble)

out
###############################################################
#devtools::install_github("rstudio/shiny")
#install.packages("devtools")
#install.packages("DT")
library(shiny)
library(devtools)
library(DT)
library(yaml)
# Define UI for slider demo app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Sliders"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar to demonstrate various slider options ----
    sidebarPanel(
      # Input: Specification of range within an interval ----
      sliderInput("range", "Range:",
                  min = min(out$year,na.rm=FALSE), max = max(out$year,na.rm=FALSE),
                  value = c(1990,1995))
    ),
    mainPanel(
            DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
          )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {

  # sorted columns are colored now because CSS are attached to them
  # output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
  #   DT::datatable(out, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE))
  # })
  minRowVal <- reactive({
    which(grepl(input$range[[1]], out$year))        #Retrieve row number that matches selected range on sliderInput
  })

  maxRowVal <- reactive({
    which(grepl(input$range[[2]], out$year))        #Retrieve row number that matches selected range on sliderInput
  })

  observeEvent(input$range, {
    output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable[minRowVal():maxRowVal(), ]
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Update the code from where I fetch the data to run display it on the app.

Comment: Can you update your app code to incorporate sample data? It's hard for other users to troubleshoot your app when they can't run it.

Comment: @jasbner's answer is correct, but the below is going to be a problem in the future. So, one possible problem is that by using `grepl`, you will only filter if both the max and min values on the slider are **exactly equal** to a value of `out$year`. You would do better by using `[]` or `dplyr::filter` to filter rows where `out$year` is greater than min and lesser than max.

Comment: @cmaher added the data

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of shiny slider bars and they can have either one or two values.  The number of values in the slider bar will be determined by how it is defined in the ui.

Because you only defined a singular slider in the initiation of the ui, there is not a second input `input$range[[2]]` when you try to extract it later in the reactive.  Therefore, you need to set a second value in your ui or you will only get a single slider instead of a range.  For example:

```
sliderInput("range", "Range:",
              min = min(out$year,na.rm=FALSE), max = max(out$year,na.rm=FALSE),
              value = c(1990,1991))
```

For an example of the difference between the two (slider bar vs. slider range) look [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/slider-bar-and-slider-range.html)

And note:

> If value is a vector of two numbers, Shiny will place two sliders on the bar, which will let your user select the endpoints of a range. If value is a single number, Shiny will create a basic slider like the one shown above.

Comment: I have just updated my code with the data table. When I ran this with your input I get the error "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: That has to do with your call to datatable.  Going forward you should look at the line that is shown on the "Stack trace" and diagnose from there.  This is a seperate issue from the `subscript out of bounds` error you were getting above.

Comment: Thanks . Seem to be getting this error . ` Warning in minRowVal():maxRowVal() :numerical expression has 85 elements: only the first used `

Comment: Sounds like you are calling datatable incorrectly still. The first argument should be a data object  (either a matrix or a data frame).  You appear to be trying to specify rows of a datatable without actually passing the table as an argument.